# Assertion failure in Notification Call

Tags: iphone

I am getting an error when I register with the notification server in debug mode on my iPhone, and looking for some ideas.

My call:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
```

it returns:

Thu Aug 27 12:27:44 unknown SpringBoard[2866] : *** Assertion failure in -[SBRemoteNotificationServer registerApplication:forEnvironment:withTypes:], /SourceCache/SpringBoard/SpringBoard-919.5/SBRemoteNotificationServer.m:633
Thu Aug 27 12:27:44 unknown SpringBoard[2866] : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no connection found for environment development'

In reading several posts, I have tried the following:

Created a new app ID.
Re-created my notification certs
re-downloaded my development profile

Cleaned all targets
rebuilt with the new app config and cert

Has anyone run into this?

Thanks in advance!

Rob

Answer (score 0):

You may find your answer at [iPhone SDK Push Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048307/iphone-sdk-push-notification)

Comment: Thanks, great link!  Unfortunately it didn't yield a solution to my issue.